# Discord.py - How to get member count not including bots?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a command that shows member count but not including bots. My code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def members(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Members in {ctx.guild.name}: {ctx.guild.member_count}")
```

However this shows count of bots and members together. Is there a way I can do it show members only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
user_count = len([x for x in ctx.guild.members if not x.bot])
```

Answer (score 1):

- This should work

```py
import random

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents().all()  # intents to see the members in the server
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="--", intents=intents)


# Command
@client.command(pass_context=True)
# to make sure that this command will only work on a discord server and not DMs
@commands.guild_only()
async def pickwinner(ctx):
    # What you did wrong
    #   for users in ctx.guild.members:
    #       `users` is a single item in the iterable `ctx.guild.names`

    # Selecting a user from the iterable (this includes user)
    # winner = random.choice(ctx.guild.members)

    # Selecting a user from the iterable (this does not include bots)
    # But the line below will be resource intensive if you are running the command
    #   on a server with a huge amount of members
    allMembers_NoBots = [x for x in ctx.guild.members if not x.bot]
    winner = random.choice(allMembers_NoBots)

    await ctx.channel.send(f"Congratulations! {winner} won the price!")


client.run("TOKEN")
```